# how to receive messages in console application from GSM modem using data received handler

Tags: c#, sms, handler, modem

I want to receive every message that is sent from GSM modem on console for that I have used DataReceivedHandler. My problem is message is always received once on the console for another message to receive I have to debug my console application that means my handler is not working properly.
One more problem is I have converted received pdu format message into text format using pduconverter.dll,from routines of pduconverter.dll I get timestamp,message text but unable to get sender's number. Here is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using GsmComm.PduConverter;


namespace readSerialData
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SerialPort serialport = new SerialPort();
        int mSpeed = 1;
        serialport.PortName = "COM16";
        serialport.BaudRate = 9600;
        serialport.Parity = Parity.None;
        serialport.DataBits = 8;
        serialport.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        serialport.Handshake = Handshake.XOnXOff;
        serialport.DtrEnable = true;
        serialport.RtsEnable = true;
        serialport.NewLine = Environment.NewLine;
        serialport.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);
        serialport.Open();
        Console.ReadKey();
        serialport.Close();

    }

    private static void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {           

            SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;            
            sp.WriteLine("AT+CNMI=1,2,0,0\r");
            sp.WriteLine("AT+CMGL=4\r");
            string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
            Console.WriteLine("Data Received:");
           string sub = indata.Substring(indata.IndexOf('0'), indata.Length -     indata.IndexOf('0'));

           IncomingSmsPdu sms = GsmComm.PduConverter.IncomingSmsPdu.Decode(sub, true);
           Console.WriteLine(sms.SmscAddress);
        Console.WriteLine(sms.UserDataText);
            Console.WriteLine(sms.GetTimestamp());
            Console.ReadKey();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Please help, I have been stuck on this from many days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `Main` method Console.ReadKey() is used to accept keystroke to exit the program, but why it is used in `DataReceivedHandler`??

Without a keystroke, DataReceivedHandler will never return. I guess this is the cause of your problem. Remove them from `DataReceivedHandler` to see if that fix your problem.

```
private static void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{ 
    ...
    Console.WriteLine(sms.GetTimestamp());
    //Console.ReadKey();

    //Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Thanks.It is now receiving every message on console.But why continuous stream of ok on receiving message?

Comment: That is a question needs more context. I suggest you ask a new question, post your code, and provide some debug information, such as what are you receiving from SerialPort (what is the value of `indata`), and provide a link to the GSMComm library (is it the [one from Github](https://github.com/welly87/GSMComm)?)

Comment: Yes, it is from Github

Comment: Do you have any idea about my second problem of sender's number??

Comment: No. But i am curious why do you get the substring of indata?

Comment: It's because message from modem comes in this format +CMT: ,30 07913.... which is in pdu format.So I have used substring that is from zero to onwards to convert that into text format.

Comment: the substring you get is the string in bold +CMT: ,3**0 07913**, it has a space, it that a problem?